# PHP - figure out why a cookie vanishes

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie

In my login system, we set a cookie to keep people logged in. I can't figure out why, but seemingly at random the cookie will just vanish and so people are logged out.

It might stick for a day, a week or a few hours even though the expiry time is fine.

Completely at a loss. To be clear: Not php session cookies, our own cookies. It's also not people wiping their own cookies, as the issue happens to me directly as well.

Login code sample:

```
    $info = $this->db->run("SELECT `password` FROM `users` WHERE (`username` = ? OR `email` = ?)", [$username, $username])->fetch();
    if ($info)
    {
        // now check password matches
        if (password_verify($password, $info['password']))
        {
            $this->user_details = $this->db->run("SELECT ".$this::$user_sql_fields." FROM `users` WHERE (`username` = ? OR `email` = ?)", [$username, $username])->fetch();

            $this->check_banned();

            $lookup = base64_encode(random_bytes(9));
            $validator = base64_encode(random_bytes(18));

            // update IP address and last login
            $this->db->run("UPDATE `users` SET `ip` = ?, `last_login` = ? WHERE `user_id` = ?", array(core::$ip, core::$date, $this->user_details['user_id']));

            $this->new_login($lookup,$validator);

            if ($stay == 1)
            {
                $secure = 0; // allows cookies for localhost dev env
                if (!empty($this->core->config('cookie_domain')))
                {
                    $secure = 1;
                }
                setcookie('gol_session', $lookup . '.' . $validator, $this->expires_date->getTimestamp(), '/', $this->cookie_domain, $secure, 1);
            }

            return true;
        }
```

The code that deals with them staying logged in:

```
if (isset($_COOKIE['gol_session']))
{
    if(strpos($_COOKIE['gol_session'], '.') !== false) 
    {
        $cookie_info = explode('.', $_COOKIE['gol_session']);

        $session_check = $this->db->run("SELECT `id`, `device-id`, `user_id`,`validator` FROM `saved_sessions` WHERE `lookup` = ? AND `expires` > NOW()", array($cookie_info[0]))->fetch(); 

        if ($session_check && hash_equals($session_check['validator'], hash('sha256', $cookie_info[1])))
        {
            // login then
            $this->user_details = $this->db->run("SELECT ".$this::$user_sql_fields." FROM `users` WHERE `user_id` = ?", array($session_check['user_id']))->fetch();

            $this->check_banned();

            // update IP address and last login
            $this->db->run("UPDATE `users` SET `ip` = ?, `last_login` = ? WHERE `user_id` = ?", array(core::$ip, core::$date, $this->user_details['user_id']));

            // update their stay logged in cookie with new details
            $lookup = base64_encode(random_bytes(9));
            $validator = base64_encode(random_bytes(18));

            $update_session_sql = "UPDATE
            `saved_sessions`
            SET
            `lookup` = ?,
            `validator` = ?,
            `expires` = ?,
            `date` = ?
            WHERE
            `id` = ? AND `user_id` = ?";
            $update_session_db = $this->db->run($update_session_sql, array($lookup, hash('sha256', $validator), $this->expires_date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), date("Y-m-d"), $session_check['id'], $session_check['user_id']));

            $check_update = $update_session_db->rowcount();

            // database was updated, so we can update the cookie
            if($check_update == 1)
            {
                $secure = 0; // allows cookies for localhost dev env
                if (!empty($this->core->config('cookie_domain')))
                {
                    $secure = 1;
                }
                setcookie('gol_session', $lookup . '.' . $validator, $this->expires_date->getTimestamp(), '/', $this->cookie_domain, $secure, 1);
            }

            $this->register_session();

            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            setcookie('gol_session', "",  time()-60, '/');
            setcookie('gol-device', "",  time()-60, '/');

            return false;
        }
```

Full login/stay logged in code can be [seen here](https://gitlab.com/liamdawe/gamingonlinux/blob/master/public_html/includes/class_user.php).

Comment: Cookies are controlled on the client side. Certainly they can be removed and many people do, manually or using other ways. Especially the "keep cookies only for this session" often results in surprises, though that browser setting definitely does make a lot of sense.

Comment: It happens to me, as well as most users of my site and I can tell you for sure I am not removing my own cookie.

Comment: No need to be rude about it. I'm not sure what answer you're expecting from such a comment? The cookies are not php session cookies, they're our own and as I mentioned, it happens to me and I am not removing them and I'm not setting anything in the browser to remove them either.

Comment: I do apologize if you understood my question as a rude comment, that was not my intention. I tried to express surprise that you only answered to a general aspect, not to the specific browser feature to delete cookies when the browser session ends. That has nothing to do with php session cookies. I experienced such effect with office computers that were only suspended at night, thus kept their browser open for days or weeks until that browser finally got restarted. But certainly it is also well worth investigating into other directions, I agree.